# How to automatically document TypedResults.Stream responses within NET 8 minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, minimal-apis

I have the following route mapped in a Mininal API application:

```
app.MapGet("api/test", async Task<Results<PushStreamHttpResult, NotFound>> (bool fail) => {
    if (fail) return TypedResults.NotFound();
    return TypedResults.Stream(stream => WriteToStream(stream), "text/plain");
}).WithSummary("Test Streaming results");

async Task WriteToStream(Stream stream) {
    // do the writing... not needed for sample code
}
```

I didn't find a way to generate the proper documentation for this `TypedResults` type in swagger/OpenAPI UI and schemas. I can do this for other result types:

```
app.MapGet("api/thisworks", async Task<
    Results<
        Ok<ApiResult>,
        BadRequest<ApiResult>,
        NotFound<ApiResult>>> () => { ... }
```

Which produces proper documentation for the many return types like this for example:

[image: Proper swagger return types documentation]

Is there a way to automatically achieve the same with `TypedResults.Stream` / `PushStreamHttpResult` ?

Comment: What is the documentation you are expecting for `PushStreamHttpResult`?

Comment: @GuruStron that's the question I should have asked myself! I understand now that the framework can't magically know what I was looking for. In fact, surprisingly, the documentation I was expecting was for a HTTP 200 status code with content type of "text/plain" since I will be streaming textual data from a database (which could be huge so I didn't want to store it in the server's memory). I solved the issue using the `.Produces` extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [swagger docs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#handle-file-downloads):

> `ApiExplorer` (the ASP.NET Core metadata component that Swashbuckle is built on) DOES NOT surface the `FileResult` type by default and so you need to explicitly tell it to with the Produces attribute:
>
> ```cs
> [HttpGet("{filename}")]
> [Produces("application/octet-stream", Type = typeof(FileResult))]
> public FileResult GetFile(string fileName)
> ```

`PushStreamHttpResult` is file result too and it seems that the same rules are applied to it also so you can use the `Produces` call, for example:

```cs
app.MapGet("api/test", async Task<Results<PushStreamHttpResult, NotFound>> (bool fail) =>
    .WithSummary("Test Streaming results")
    .Produces(200, contentType: "text/plain" )
```

If all `PushStreamHttpResult` are plain texts then you can try to automate it with operation filter:

```
// sample implementation, adjust for production
public sealed class PushStreamHttpResultFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var returnType = context.MethodInfo.ReturnType;

        if (ContainsPushStream(returnType))
        {
            // adds plain text only if no 200 are defined
            operation.Responses.TryAdd("200", new OpenApiResponse
            {
                Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
                {
                    ["text/plain"] = new OpenApiMediaType()
                    {
                        Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        bool ContainsPushStream(Type type)
        {
            if (type == typeof(PushStreamHttpResult))
                return true;
            if (!type.IsConstructedGenericType)
                return false;
            if (type.IsConstructedGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
                return ContainsPushStream(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
            return type.GetGenericArguments().Any(t => t == typeof(PushStreamHttpResult));
        }
    }
}
```

And add it to filters:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
{
    o.OperationFilter<PushStreamHttpResultFilter>();
});
```

Comment: I ended up using `Produces` as it's not that annoying to use it in a single place :-) since there's only one single API endpoint which needs "streaming". Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Produces<T>`:

```
app.MapGet("api/test", async Task<Results<PushStreamHttpResult, NotFound>> (bool fail) => {
    if (fail) return TypedResults.NotFound();
    return TypedResults.Stream(stream => WriteToStream(stream), "text/plain");
})
    .Produces<NotFound>()
    .Produces<PushStreamHttpResult>()
    .WithSummary("Test Streaming results");
```

Result:
[image]